# List of Adobe Lightroom resources

Tags: lightroom, software

I'd like to make a list of [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/) resources: Blogs, sites, tutorials, and so on...

Anything worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some sites you may find useful:

- http://lightroomkillertips.com/ [Video tutorials, present tips]
- http://www.presetsheaven.com/ [1,000s of free presets]
- http://lightroom-news.com/ [Latest news, releases]
- http://www.flickr.com/groups/presets/discuss/72157612664073371/ [Impressive collection of user presets]
- http://www.photoshopsupport.com/lightroom/tutorials.html [Tutorials]
- http://digitalmedia.oreilly.com/lightroom/ [Lightroom tips]

Answer (score 12):

One of the best tips I can offer is to use the help popup hotkey (which is sadly far under-publicized):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> on Windows

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> on Mac OS

You get a module-specific popup that shows all the hotkeys for that module. Once you learn the hotkeys, your workflow becomes much smoother and faster.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that comes to my mind is: http://lightroomkillertips.com/

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.ericscouten.com/2009/09/lightroom-2-technique-how-i-organize-my-catalog-and-why-2009-edition

That one helped me settle on a workflow and understand the compromises and limitations.

**Update:** The old link is now broken. Eric Scouten updated the article and has published a new [2012 edition](http://ericscouten.com/blog/2012/03/05/lightroom-technique-how-i-organize-my-catalog-and-why-2012-edition).

Comment: Fantastic resource. And very interesting discussion also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wade Heninger (formerly UI designer for LR) has a blog that he does weekly roundups of all things LR: http://heninger.org/index_files/tag-lightroom.html

Answer (score 0):

Here my favorite:

http://www.freelightroompresets.net (free collection - I love the vintage effect)

http://www.lightgram.com (premium collection - amazing presets that emulates Instagram)

Answer (score 0):

And another couple good links ...

http://scottkelby.com/10-things-i-would-tell-new-lightroom-users/ and http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/

Answer (score -1):

Here is a BEAUTIFUL book I am using for my lightroom Class

["The Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3 Book:"](http://books.google.com/books?id=QdLVQgAACAAJ&dq=adobe%20lightroom%203&hl=en&ei=JTGwTebSJ8jn0QGy05CkCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CEgQ6AEwAA)

Answer (score -1):

A few of my links attached ....

http://www.lightroomqueen.com/
and https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/categories/photoshop_family_photoshop_lightroom